# jQuery add dynamically cell to a static cell into table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to create static/dynamic table. All cell `<th>` and the first two columns `<td>` of row are static. Content others cells I want to create dynamically using jQuery script.

I do not know how I start. Data to cell I have saved at JSON format (array) as:

```
{
"EX1":[["1","8","16","24"]],
"EX2":[["0","100200","109f","ffffffff"]]
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="personDataTable" style="border: 1px #e3ffg3 solid; text-align: center;">
  <tr class="bg02">
    <th colspan="2">Name</th>
    <th width="100px">Sensor 1</th>
    <th width="100px">Sensor 2</th>
    <th width="100px">Sensor 3</th>
    <th width="100px">Sensor 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td class="bg02">A</td>
    <td class="bg02">Out64H</td>
    <td>element[index]</td>
    <td>element[index+1]</td>
    <td>element[index+2]</td>
    <td>element[index+3]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td class="bg02">R</td>
    <td class="bg02">In128Birh</td>
    <td>element[index]</td>
    <td>element[index+1]</td>
    <td>element[index+2]</td>
    <td>element[index+3]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Static text in the every `<tr>` is necassary because text is not in json file. 
Can ask for help with create javascript script?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zr6z70g/3/

The jQuery code is this way:

```
var data = {
  "EX1":[["1","8","16","24"]],
  "EX2":[["0","100200","109f","ffffffff"]]
};

var data1 = data.EX1[0];
var data2 = data.EX2[0];

$(document).ready(function(){
  var row1cells = $("#row1 td");
  var row2cells = $("#row2 td");

  for (var index=0; index<4; index++) {
    $(row1cells[index+2]).html(data1[index]);
    $(row2cells[index+2]).html(data2[index]);
  }
});
```

**For multiple EX data, do it this way:**

```
var exCount = 2;

var data = {
  "EX1":[["1","8","16","24"]],
  "EX2":[["0","100200","109f","ffffffff"]]
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  for (var index=1; index<=exCount; index++) {
    var cells  = $("#row"+index+" td");
    var values = data["EX"+index][0];

    for (var jndex=0; jndex<4; jndex++) {
      $(cells[jndex+2]).html(values[jndex]);
      $(cells[jndex+2]).html(values[jndex]);
    }
  }
});
```

More details for multiple EX, see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zr6z70g/7/

Answer (score 0):

This code is suitable for me, but variable *EX* are more than one hundred.

```
var data = {
  "EX1":[["1","8","16","24"]],
  "EX2":[["0","100200","109f","ffffffff"]]
};

var data1 = data.EX1[0];
var data2 = data.EX2[0];

$(document).ready(function(){
  var row1cells = $("#row1 td");
  var row2cells = $("#row2 td");

 for (var index=0; index<4; index++) {
  $(row1cells[index+2]).html(data1[index]);
  $(row2cells[index+2]).html(data2[index]);
 }
});
```

I tried modify the code using **for loop** following. This solution do not work correctly.

```
var data = {
  "EX1":[["1","8","16","24"]],
  "EX2":[["0","100200","109f","ffffffff"]]
};

var data1 = data.EX1[0];
var data2 = data.EX2[0];

$(document).ready(function(){
for (j=1; j<4; j++) {
  var pom = "row"+[j]+"cells";
  var pom2 = "#row"+[j]+" td";
  var pom3 = "$"+'("'+pom2+'")';

  for (var index=0; index<4; index++) {
    $(pom3+[index+2]).html(data[j][index]);
    }
   }
 });
```

Can ask for help with modify? Thanks